# How can I prevent the cells in my table from going out of the table and have a fixed width?

Tags: html, css

I am learning how to design html templates for newsletters and there was a suggestion to use blank cells instead of padding to avoid wonkiness of email clients. While using a blank  tag with a fixed **width** attribute to  get vertical padding is working fine, when I try to use  with **width** attribute to get horizontal padding my table completely breaks. The table's width get's reduced to half. Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong ?

[This is what ends up happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WjRq.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Test News Letter</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>

<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
    <table id="container" role="presentation" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <table align="center" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
            <!--Header-->
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#70bbd9" style="line-height: 0; font-size: 0;" height="40">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" bgcolor="#70bbd9">
                    <img src="someGif.gif" alt="News Letter" width="300" height="230" style="display: block;"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#70bbd9" style="line-height: 0; font-size: 0;" height="30">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>

            <!--Content-->
            <tr>
                <td style="line-height: 0; font-size: 0;" height="40">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="line-height: 0; font-size: 0; " width="40">&nbsp;</td>
                <td bgcolor="#ffffff">
                    <p style="margin: 0;">Row 2</p>
                </td>
                <td style="line-height: 0; font-size: 0; " width="40">&nbsp;</td>   
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="line-height: 0; font-size: 0;" height="40">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#ee4c50">
                    <p style="margin: 0;">Row 3</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **Row 2** have 3 `<td>` so it will have 3 columns but your others row only have one cell. If you absolutly want to use this method, you have to set all your single `<td>` to fill space of 3 columns.

So, add `colspan="3"` on each other cell.`<td colspan="3" ... >`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Test News Letter</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>

<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
    <table id="container" role="presentation" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <table align="center" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
            <!--Header-->
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#70bbd9" colspan="3" style="line-height: 0; font-size: 0;" height="40">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" colspan="3"  bgcolor="#70bbd9">
                    <img src="someGif.gif" alt="News Letter" width="300" height="230" style="display: block;"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#70bbd9" colspan="3"  style="line-height: 0; font-size: 0;" height="30">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>

            <!--Content-->
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3"  style="line-height: 0; font-size: 0;" height="40">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="line-height: 0; font-size: 0; " width="40">&nbsp;</td>
                <td bgcolor="#ffffff">
                    <p>Row 2</p>
                </td>
                <td style="line-height: 0; font-size: 0; " width="40">&nbsp;</td>   
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="line-height: 0; font-size: 0;" height="40">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#ee4c50">
                    <p>Row 3</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```